# MySQL: calculate percent in subgroup

Tags: mysql

I have a list of names with country and city.

```
| COUNTRY | CITY | NAME | ID|
```

I need to find a count of each name grouped by country and city. I also need percentage of each name  WITHIN each city/country. For example:

RESULTS

```
SELECT count(ID), country, city, name
from table NAME
GROUP BY country, city, name
```

How do I calculate percentage of each name  WITHIN each city/country?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your query doesn't compute the count of each name grouped by city and state but rather the count of each id grouped by name, city and country. Assuming this is what you wanted, then the percents might be calculated like this:

```
 SELECT count(N.ID) as NameCount
      , count(N.ID) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NAME WHERE Country = N.Country AND City = N.City) as NamePercent 
      , N.Name
      , N.Country
      , N.City
 FROM NAME N
 GROUP BY N.country, N.city, N.Name
```

Here's a test fiddle I've created for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/875026/1/0

For the second question - from the comments,

> How to calculate AVE of name occurance across different cities grouped by a country. For example: count of Mikes in NY-2, Chicago-4, LA-5. So ave for Mike in US is 3.6

You might do something like this:

```
SELECT  Name
      , Country
      , AVG(NameCount) NameAvgAcrossCountry
FROM 
   (SELECT count(N.ID) as NameCount
         , count(N.ID) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NAME WHERE Country = N.Country AND City = N.City) as NamePercent 
         , N.Name
         , N.Country
         , N.City
    FROM NAME N
    GROUP BY N.country, N.city, N.Name) NamesQuery
GROUP BY Name, Country
```

Comment: How to calculate AVE of name occurance across different cities grouped by a country. For example: count of Mikes in NY-2, Chicago-4, LA-5. So ave for Mike in US is 3.6

Comment: You might do that with a query that uses this initial query as a sub-query. That's really a different question so you should have asked it as a separate question but I'll update my answer for you..